# SSH Log: "Accepted password for user..."

Tags: linux, ssh, logging

I have only port 29999 open for SSH connections. But in the log file I see entries like this:

Accepted password for user1 from 190.101.200.100 port 55805 ssh2

saying that a connection was accepted from port 55805. What does it mean? that someone was able to hack the server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That port number is the client's source port, not the destination port.